# Awkward riddle that is confusing

Tags: riddle

What do I find funny about the following statement?: ~E ∨ G

Hint:

> I am immature

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You find it funny because

> you're an immature logician

and read it as

> not E or G, which makes you giggle because it sound like naughty orgy

Comment: I hate when I google it.